# Solr DataImport set field to specific value

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I am trying to import documents from one collection to another using **SolrEntityProcessor** in */dataimport* handler.  I want set a field ***origin*** in the new document that will identify where the data came from.  This should be the same value for each imported document and there is no column in the source collection that I can use as a field mapping.  Is this possible or am I out of luck?  This is an example of what I hope for, in this example I want to set ***origin** to the value "collection2":

```
<dataConfig>
<document>
      <entity name="Master"
                    processor="SolrEntityProcessor"
                    query="*:*"
                    url="https://<solr site>/solr/Master"
                    qt="/select"
                    rows="10"
                    cursorMark="true">

        <field column="content" name="content_txt"/>
        ...
        <field column="origin" value="collection2" />
    </entity>

</document>
</dataConfig>
```

Comment: See if using the TemplateTransformer as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936032/static-field-for-document-in-data-import-handlerfor-solr works for you

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks, that's what I was looking for.